# Android Retrofit + rxjava parsing JSON

Tags: android, json, retrofit, rx-android

I'm new to Retrofit and RX java and I'm trying to parse the following JSON:

```
{
   "result": 
    {
        "offset": 0,
        "limit": 2,
        "count": 408,
        "sort": "",
        "results":[
            {
                "_id": "1",
                "iid": "338",
                "sv": "0",
                "sd": "20000101000000",
                "vtyp": "1",
                "sno": "0001",            
            },
            {
                "_id": "2",
                "iid": "339",
                "sv": "0",
                "sd": "20000101000000",
                "vtyp": "1",
                "sno": "0001",          
            }

        ]
    }

}
```

I'm only interested in the array of objects contained in "results".  From what I've been able to find I should be implementing a JsonDeserializer to get at that data and use .setConverter when building the RestAdapter.  Here's what I have now:

```
class MyDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Pojo> {
    @Override
    public Station deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
        JsonElement element = json.getAsJsonObject().get("results");
        return new Gson().fromJson(element, Pojo.class);
    }
```

I want the retrofit GET call to return

```
Observable<List<Pojo>>
```

that represents the objects in "results"

my Pojo.class looks like this:

```
public class Pojo {
    public String _id;
    public String iid;
    public String sv;
    public String sd;
    public String vtyp;
}
```

Write now I get this error when I try to call the API, so I think I've got something wrong in the Json deserialization:

```
retrofit.RetrofitError: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create below three pojo classes

1. MyPojo.java

   ```
   public class MyPojo
   {
       private Result result;

       public Result getResult ()
       {
           return result;
       }

       public void setResult (Result result)
       {
           this.result = result;
       }

   }
   ```
2. Result.java

   ```
   public class Result
   {
   private String limit;

   private String sort;

   private Results[] results;

   private String count;

   private String offset;

   public String getLimit ()
   {
       return limit;
   }

   public void setLimit (String limit)
   {
       this.limit = limit;
   }

   public String getSort ()
   {
       return sort;
   }

   public void setSort (String sort)
   {
       this.sort = sort;
   }

   public Results[] getResults ()
   {
       return results;
   }

   public void setResults (Results[] results)
   {
       this.results = results;
   }

   public String getCount ()
   {
       return count;
   }

   public void setCount (String count)
   {
       this.count = count;
   }

   public String getOffset ()
   {
       return offset;
   }

   public void setOffset (String offset)
   {
       this.offset = offset;
   }
   ```

   }
3. Results.java

   ```
   public class Results
   {
   private String sno;

   private String _id;

   private String iid;

   private String vtyp;

   private String sd;

   private String sv;

   public String getSno ()
   {
       return sno;
   }

   public void setSno (String sno)
   {
       this.sno = sno;
   }

   public String get_id ()
   {
       return _id;
   }

   public void set_id (String _id)
   {
       this._id = _id;
   }

   public String getIid ()
   {
       return iid;
   }

   public void setIid (String iid)
   {
       this.iid = iid;
   }

   public String getVtyp ()
   {
       return vtyp;
   }

   public void setVtyp (String vtyp)
   {
       this.vtyp = vtyp;
   }

   public String getSd ()
   {
       return sd;
   }

   public void setSd (String sd)
   {
       this.sd = sd;
   }

   public String getSv ()
   {
       return sv;
   }

   public void setSv (String sv)
   {
       this.sv = sv;
   }
   ```

   }

write below code in your activity

```
private RestAdapter restAdapter;

private ApiListeners apiListener;

restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).setEndpoint("Your Base Url").build();
apiListener = restAdapter.create(ApiListeners.class);

apiListener.getData(new Callback<MyPojo>() 
        {
            @Override
            public void success(MyPojo pojo, Response response)
            {

            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) 
            {

            }
        });
```

Create below listener

```
public interface ApiListeners 
{
    @GET("/yourApiTag")
    public void getData(retrofit.Callback<MyPojo> responseVo);
}
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid creating three classes since they aren't needed at all.  That was why I was trying to use the Json deserializer.  I can parse the data if I do it the way you suggest, but I'd like to do it without the unnecessary classes if possible